# Compare each column for two spark dataframe & create new columns for result

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

- I have 2 pyspark dataframes.
- Both will be having equal number of columns usually.
- Columns name are different in both dataframes.
- For first column in both dataframes values can be same or different.
- I want to compare both dataframes, like first column in both dfs then second column in both dfs and so on.
- For compare result I want to create a new column, showing match/no_match/null_in_1st/null_in_2nd and so on.
- I want one final df that should have all column names & compared result side by side for each column.

**NOTE** : I have lot of columns so have to tackle that using some loop instead of type each column in code.

e.g. **dataframe1**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 4 |
| xyz |  |
| mno | 5 |

e.g. **dataframe2**

| Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 3 |
| xyz | 4 |
| mno |  |

**Result dataframe**

| Column X | Column X_result |
| --- | --- |
| abc | match |
| def | no_match |
| xyz | dataframe1_null |
| mno | dataframe2_null |

I want one final df that should have all column names & compared result side by side for each column.

**Result dataframe**

| Column X | Column X_result |
| --- | --- |
| abc | match |
| def | no_match |
| xyz | dataframe1_null |
| mno | dataframe2_null |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a very simple approach of CASE STATEMENTS.

Data :

```
val df1 = Seq(("abc","2"),
             ("def","4"),
              ("xyz",null),
              ("mno","5")
             ).toDF("colA","colb")

val df2 = Seq(("abc","2"),
             ("def","3"),
              ("xyz","4"),
              ("mno",null)
             ).toDF("colC","colD")
```

hence the data looks like -

```
+----+----+
|colA|colb|
+----+----+
| abc|   2|
| def|   4|
| xyz|null|
| mno|   5|
+----+----+

+----+----+
|colC|colD|
+----+----+
| abc|   2|
| def|   3|
| xyz|   4|
| mno|null|
+----+----+
```

Method 1: Join + Case Statements

```
val df_result = df1.join(df2,df1("colA") === df2("colC"),"left")
                   .select(df1("colA"),df1("colB"),df2("colD"))
                   .withColumn("Column X_result",
                              when(df1("colB")===df2("colD"),"match")
                             .when(df1("colB").isNull,"dataframe1_null")
                             .when(df2("colD").isNull,"dataframe2_null")
                             .otherwise("no_match")
                            )
                  .drop("colB","colD")
                  .withColumnRenamed("colA","Column X")

display(df_result)
```

Method 2 : Join + iterative Method with MAP + if-else

```
val joined_df = df1.join(df2,df1("colA") === df2("colC"))
                        .select(df1("colA"),df1("colB"),df2("colD"))
    
    val df_results = joined_df.map(row =>{ 
                             val colx = if (row.getString(1)==null) {"dataframe1_null"}
                                       else if (row.getString(2)==null) {"dataframe2_null"}
                                       else if (row.getString(1)==row.getString(2)) {"match"}
                                       else {"no_match"}
                              (row.getString(0),colx)
                             }
                            ).toDF("Column X","Column X_result")
    display(df_results)
```

Result -

[image: result]